# Kivy how can I customize video's size and position

Tags: python, video, kivy

So I'm able to use the `video` library to play video on my GUI, but I realized the video was always placed at the middle with the default size, as there are no attribute like `pos` or `size` in `video class`. I would like to know if there are any way I can size and place the video like other widgets/buttons/labels.

Answer (score 1):

The following example illustrates sizing and placing a video.

## Example

In the following demo, we are using `AnchorLayout`. You can replace it with any [Layouts](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/layouts.html) ([BoxLyout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html#module-kivy.uix.boxlayout), [FloatLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html#module-kivy.uix.floatlayout), etc.), [Widget](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html), etc. and use [pos](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos) or [pos_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint).

### main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'top'
    Video:
        source: 'rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov'
        state: 'play'
        keep_ratio: True
        allow_stretch: True
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
"""))
```

Comment: Hi @ikolim , thanks for the answer. Indeed that gives some freedom of sizing and placing the video, but the video can only align to the anchored layout right?  I would like my video to be placed at the right center but not touching the border, is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Update:  I've manage to done it by using ``floatlayout`` and setting a ``pos`` under ``Video:``

Comment: Good. In my example, I have used `AnchorLayout` as a demo. You can use any `Layouts` including `FloatLayout`. "***If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer.***" [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)